# How do I add module theme elements to drupalSettings

Tags: 8

I have a module "flot_d8" which is a wrapper for a javascript library. I would like to streamline the way this library is called from other modules (flot_examples in this case). I currently call it like this from src/Controller/FlotExample.php

```
$data[] = [
  'data' => [
    [0, 12],
    [7, 12],
    NULL,
    [7, 2.5],
    [12, 2.5],
  ],
];
$div_id = 'placeholder';
$drupalsettings['flot_d8'][$div_id] = ['data' => $data];
$output[] = [
  '#attached' => [
    'drupalSettings' => $drupalsettings,
  ],
  '#theme' => 'flot_d8_my_template',
  '#data' => $series,
  '#options' => NULL,
  '#div_id' => $div_id,
];
```

Is there a way to force the flot_d8 module to add the $data to drupalSettings instead of passing this task to the flot_examples module in every single class function?

I tried this

```
function flot_d8_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
//$div_id = $output["#div_id'];
//$data = $output['#data'];
//$options = $output['#options'];
  $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['flot_d8'][$div_id] = ['data' => $data, 'options' => $options];
}
```

But I know this isn't the right way to access $div_id, $data, and $options. Can I use the value in $output['#div_id'] in hook_page_attachments_alter()?

Comment: I think you could make this into element and use the theme function only tu supplement the element itself. So users would call ['#type' => 'flot'...] instead of ['#theme' => 'flot'...].

Comment: Any good tutorials out there on Drupal 8 element design?

Comment: Is there a way to use a preprocess function to both view the theme variables, and set the '#attached' attribute to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an Element within the parent module. This element includes code to add the data and options to drupalSettings. It also determines which libraries are needed and includes them.